# Why are these query results not equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on some sorting of SQL results on a webpage, which hasn't quite been working correctly. There is some sort of disconnect when I sort the results by count. Can anyone see any obvious cause of this?

**This query is grouping counts by employee ID:**

```
SELECT userid, username, COUNT(DISTINCT maintlist.maintid) as thecount 
from Userlist inner join maintlist ON MaintList.enteredby = convert(varchar(20),userid) 
 inner join maintnotes on maintnotes.maintid = maintlist.maintid 
 where deptnum <> '0' AND notedate between '2015-10-01' AND '11/1/2015' 
 group by userid, username order by thecount DESC;
```

**This query is run after each employee ID is fetched:**

(First employees are queried for)

```
strSQL = "SELECT userid, username from Userlist where deptnum <> '0' order by "&sorton&" "&sortonorder&";"
```

Then the query for the count is performed:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT maintlist.maintid) 
FROM [Maint].[dbo].[MaintNotes] inner join maintlist ON MaintList.maintid = maintnotes.maintid 
WHERE maintnotes.enteredby = '143' 
AND notedate between '2015-10-01' AND '11/1/2015';
```

The numbers are off for every ID, but I am not sure where the disconnect is?
Thanks!

Comment: Why you are putting filter WHERE maintnotes.enteredby = '143' in second query

Comment: That's just one example, but that query is after the employee ID is already fetched.

Comment: the queries look ok. you could check the difference of `maintlist.maintid` which are listed in both these queries after removing the `count`. it might give you a hint as so why there is a difference